# parameter marker count incorrect

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, parameters

Why i am getting ERROR [HY000] parameter marker count incorrect.
I am using SQLite3 Odbc Driver on my VB.Net Project and here's my code structure.

On my DBClass

```
Imports System.Data.Odbc

Public Class DbClass

    Private DbConnection As New OdbcConnection("DRIVER=SQLite3 ODBC Driver;Database=E:\VB.NET Projects\MyBeDb.db;LongNames=0;Timeout=1000;NoTXN=0; SyncPragma=NORMAL;StepAPI=0;")
    Private DbCommand As New OdbcCommand
    Private DbDataAdapter As New OdbcDataAdapter
    Private DbParameter As New List(Of OdbcParameter)
    Private DbRecordCount As Integer = 0
    Private DbDataTable As DataTable

    Sub ExecuteQuery(_Query As String)
        DbRecordCount = 0
        DbConnection.Open()
        DbCommand = New OdbcCommand(_Query, DbConnection)
        DbParameter.ForEach(Sub(p) DbCommand.Parameters.Add(p))
        DbParameter.Clear()
        DbDataTable = New DataTable
        DbDataAdapter = New OdbcDataAdapter(DbCommand)
        DbRecordCount = DbDataAdapter.Fill(DbDataTable)
        If DbConnection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then DbConnection.Close()
    End Sub

    Sub AddParameters(_Name As String, _Value As Object)
        Dim NewParam As New OdbcParameter(_Name, _Value)
        DbParameter.Add(NewParam)
    End Sub

    Sub Authenticate(_Username As String, _Password As String)
        AddParameters("Un", _Username)
        AddParameters("Pw", _Password)
        ExecuteQuery("SELECT * FROM UserAccounts WHERE [Username] LIKE @Un AND [Password] LIKE @Pw;")
    End Sub

End Class
```

On Button Click

```
    Private myDb As New DbClass

    
    Private Sub Login_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Login.Click
        Try
            myDb.Authenticate("Admin", "Password")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message & Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine & ex.StackTrace)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

I tried using ? instead of @ and it didn't throw any exception message if i mistype a username and password.

Comment: Have you tried AddParameters("@Un", _Username)?

Comment: You need to include the parameter marker in your addParameters call. So "@un" and "@pw". Also, consider using password hashing and salting so that you aren't storing or passing passwords as plaintext.

Comment: Problem solve, and it's fault to forgot adding @ on adding a parameters, i realize this after i switch from sqlite odbc to sqlite nugget.